# How to write HTML code

Tags: html

I am new to HTML coding.
I would like to have HTML code for following:
Say i have two Buttons, Button1 and Button2. Initially Button1 is enabled and Button2 is disabled. Open clicking Button1, a label should be displayed with value 1,2,(say time ticker). Once it reached say 30 seconds, then Button2 should be enabled.
How can  write HTML code for the above?
I am expecting the code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<button type="button" name="button1" enabled="enabled" onclick="WaitLoad()">Click Button1</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<label> name="Label1"></label>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" name="button2" disabled="disabled">Click Button2</button>
</form>
<script type="text/vbscript">
sub WaitLoad()
{
    for i=1 to 30
        Label1.text=i
    next
    button2.enable=true
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. There is not such a property called "enabled". 2. Use JavaScript, unless you want your code to only work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Please start use JavaScript for client side coding. 99.9999999999% people and browser supports Javascript

Comment: Here you can find info about timing events in JS: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

By default a button, or any input element is enabled, so you don't need to specify that an element is enabled, only when the element is disabled.

Your logic is good, but just some thing you'll pick up when actually writing HTML/JS..

Javascript has a function called [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), which would work perfectly for you.

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) executes some code after a timeperiod has passed, so you could do the following;

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function WaitLoad()
{
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('button2').disabled=false",30000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <button type="button" name="button1" onclick="WaitLoad()">Click Button1</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label name="Label1"></label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" name="button2" id="button2" disabled="disabled">Click Button2</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**30000 = 30 seconds** (setTimeout must take the wait time in milliseconds)
It is also best practice to add any javascript functions you write/add into the head of your HTML.

There are a lot of tutorials online which will teach you the basics of writing HTML, and the does and don'ts

Answer (score 0):

first of all there is no such thing called enable as attribute for button.in onclick function,
use **[setTimeout(code, millisec)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)**

**code**: Required. The function that will be executed

**millisec**: Required. The number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByName('button2')[0].disabled = false;
} ,30000);
```